# Implementing Djoser and JWT in Django for user authentication

Tags: django, djoser

I am implementing user authentication in my first Django app. I decided to follow a tutorial from [here](https://lewiskori.com/blog/user-registration-and-authorization-on-a-django-api-with-djoser-and-json-web-tokens/).

I just finished the implementation, and it happens that when I add the following route     `path('api/app', include('app.urls'))`,to the url.py, I get  the following error, which crashes t he platform:

```
....
File "/Users/frankydoul/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 123, in _check_pattern_startswith_slash
    if regex_pattern.startswith(('/', '^/', '^\\/')) and not regex_pattern.endswith('/'):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Removing it let the platform running. Is anybody familiar with the error please ?

Comment: It's a recursion error, so I'm guessing you've put this in 'app/urls.py' and not the project's main urls.py. Or this is the project's main urls.py and you should be referencing the Django app that provides the real application. In the tutorial that is the "accounts" app. If you don't understand the difference, please refer to [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project) - specifically the difference between a Django project and a Django app.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was as simple as you described. I moved it to the core/url.py and it works fine. thank you  @Melvyn

Comment: @Melvyn,  I am now trying to perform the test that he suggest at the end of the tutorial, and I get: $ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: database "test_newworld_development" already exists

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_newworld_development', or 'no' to cancel: 

Is there a way not to destroy the existing database, since there is already some data in there ?

Comment: This is the test database, it's not the real database. Django  prefixes the real name with "test_" to create a fresh database for testing, that has the schema but no data. If however, a test crashes without being able to destroy the database, then you get this error and can safely destroy the old one.